# Web service calling problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, security

From ASP.NET web site I'm calling web service (which requires certificate). When I testing it on localhost (debugging) it works, but on IIS 6 (windows server 2003) it does not works and throws an exception:

> The request failed with HTTP status
>   403: Forbidden.

Here is the code, how I'm calling web service:

```
  Service service = new Service();
  service.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate("certificate path", "password"));
  service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidationCallBack);
  Result res = service.GetResult();


  private static bool ValidationCallBack(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
  {
       return true;
  }
```

What is the reason of this error and how can I avoid this?

I've tried web service call with winForms and it works fine on server. So I think it is IIS problem...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this you should look at this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318380)

> 403 - Forbidden. You can receive this
>   generic 403 status code if the Web
>   site has no default document set, and
>   the site is not set to allow Directory
>   Browsing. For more information about
>   how to resolve this problem, click the
>   following article number to view the
>   article in the Microsoft Knowledge
>   Base: 
>  [320051](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320051)  How to
>   configure the default document in
>   Internet Information Services

> 403.7 - Client certificate required. You have configured the server to
>   require a certificate for client
>   authentication, but you do not have a
>   valid client certificate
>   installed.
>  [186812](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186812/EN-US)  PRB:
>   Error Message: 403.7 Forbidden: Client
>   Certificate Required

Comment: Default document is set and directory browsing is allowed. But problem was not solved.

Comment: @Vano Maisuradze" try this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/3d3357fd-bcf2-4b1c-a3f6-c338a04daffa/)

Answer (score 0):

You should enable [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342%28VS.90%29.aspx) on the server side for a better understanding os this issue. You will see a better exception message or something that will give you a clue.